# Как в проекте на Delphi для Android реализовать слушатели, имплементирующие интерфейс, определенный в Java-библиотеке

Tags: java, android, delphi, интерфейс

Я разрабатываю проект для Android, использую Delphi и при этом хочу использовать библиотеки, написанные на Java. Конкретно меня интересует класс TJAudioRecord.
Мне удается вызывать методы классов, определенных в Java-библиотеке, но я не могу разобраться, как перехватывать события. Как описать в своем коде на Delphi и как зарегистрировать слушатели, имплементирующие интерфейсы, описанные в этих библиотеках? На Java нужный мне слушатель выглядит так:

```
public OnRecordPositionUpdateListener mListener = new OnRecordPositionUpdateListener() {
    public void onPeriodicNotification(AudioRecord recorder) {
        // мой код
    }
    public void onMarkerReached(AudioRecord recorder) {
        // мой код
    }
};
```

Как написать заголовок соответствующего слушателя и его методов на Delphi и как такой слушатель зарегистрировать, чтобы он мог получать события?

Comment: Ничего не понял... можно потратить еще пару сотен знаков и пояснить чего вы хотите?

Comment: @Barmaley Человек, видимо, хочет использовать Java-библиотеки в проекте, который он делает на дельфи для андроида. Если эта моя угадка верна, то вопрос (inho) имеет право на существование, только заголовок надо изменить.

Comment: Можно, например, вот в эту сторону посмотреть http://aziga.x10.mx/delphi/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=28&Itemid=33

Comment: @ m. vokhm, вы правы, я использовать Java-библиотеки  (unit Androidapi.JNI.Media; class TJAudioRecord ) в проекте на дельфи для андроида. Посмотрел aziga....,

Comment: @ m. vokhm, вы правы, я использовать Java-библиотеки  (unit Androidapi.JNI.Media; class TJAudioRecord ) в проекте на дельфи для андроида. функции в мой проект работает, но с собития не могу разобраться. Код на верху делает на C то что мне надо, создает собитие с двух процедурь. Не знаю как будет на Дельфи?Посмотрел aziga...., не очень просто, кроме тово начинаеть с нуля.

Comment: @Joro, я попытался переформулировать ваш вопрос, немного подробнее изложив суть проблемы. Посмотрите (когда мою правку проверят), я правильно понял и выразил смысл вашего вопроса?

Comment: @ m. vokhm, Спасибо, ето точно!